# Issue with installing models module

Tags: python, database, model, sqlalchemy

I am taking a webdev with python class and the current lecture involves creating databases with sqlalchemy. I have attached the script. In order for lines 7 and 10 to work, the "models" module needs to be installed. However, when I try to install the module, I get the following error:

```
Collecting models
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/3c/ac1ddde60c02b5a46993bd3c6f4c66a9dbc100059da8333178ce17a22db5/models-0.9.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\nikol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_om8dbe7\models\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        import models
      File "C:\Users\nikol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_om8dbe7\models\models\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from base import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

I have found that models has a newer version called doqu, but I can't seem to get doqu to work with this code. I tried manually installing models but didn't succeed.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = ""
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you are working with sqlalchemy with Flask, either follow the [sqlalchemy tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html) or the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) quick start if you don't mind coupling your project tightly with Flask.  The package you are trying to use are unsupported or has very out-of-date/poor documentation ([Tutorial on `docu`](https://pythonhosted.org/doqu/tutorial.html) has all these out-of-date warnings).

Comment: Are you sure that the tutorial instructs you to install the `models`, instead of writing a `models` module that contains your SQLAlchemy models? The former doesn't make sense. Please include a link or a reference of some kind to the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what your class is asking of you. You are not asked to install the [`models` project](https://pypi.org/project/models/) (which is a project that was last released in 2010, and as you found, broken, since renamed several times, and is indeed now called [Doqu](https://bitbucket.org/neithere/doqu/src/default/)).

You are supposed to create **your own** `models.py` module, to store your SQLAlchemy models in; it is a common pattern to use that name in your projects.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I saw that "models" deals with databases and assumed that was what was being imported.